Optimizing a function to search for setwise noncoprime binary strings
I am trying to write a function that is supposed to return a list of all complementary k-tuples of integers consisting of only 0's and 1's such that every tuple is not coprime setwise (i.e. GCD of all k integers is > 1). The integers are considered integers in base 10, despite having only 2 digits.
My original version of the code that returns the correct result looks like this:
Clear[NonCoprimeList];
NonCoprimeList[n_, m_] := NonCoprimeList[n, m] = 
  If[n == 0, {{}}, If[m == 1, {{FromDigits[IntegerDigits[2^n - 1, 2]]}},
    FullList = Flatten[Table[Table[
          Prepend[FromDigits /@
            IntegerDigits[2^(Flatten[Position[Reverse[IntegerDigits[i, 2]], 0]] - 1).# &
/@ (Reverse[IntegerDigits[#, 10, Count[IntegerDigits[i, 2], 0]]] & /@ #[[j]]), 2], 
           FromDigits[IntegerDigits[i, 2]]], {j, Length[#]}] &[
        NonCoprimeList[Count[IntegerDigits[i, 2], 0], m - 1]], {i, 2^(n - 1), 2^n - 2}], 1]]]
T[n_, k_] := Length[#] &[Select[GCD @@ # > 1 &][NonCoprimeList[n, k]]];
T[8, 3]

The output of this code is T[8, 3] = 98.
Instead of applying Select[GCD @@ # > 1 &][...] at the end to the whole array, I want to place it inside the function definition and use the fact that k integers cannot have GCD > 1 if k - 1 are already setwise coprime. So I am changing the code as follows:
Clear[NonCoprimeList];
NonCoprimeList[n_, m_] := NonCoprimeList[n, m] = 
  If[n == 0, {{}}, If[m == 1, {{FromDigits[IntegerDigits[2^n - 1, 2]]}},
    FullList = Select[GCD @@ # > 1 &][Flatten[Table[Table[          
           Prepend[FromDigits /@
             IntegerDigits[2^(Flatten[Position[Reverse[IntegerDigits[i, 2]], 0]] - 1).# &
/@ (Reverse[IntegerDigits[#, 10, Count[IntegerDigits[i, 2], 0]]] & /@ #[[j]]), 2], 
            FromDigits[IntegerDigits[i, 2]]], {j, Length[#]}] &[
         NonCoprimeList[Count[IntegerDigits[i, 2], 0], m - 1]], {i, 2^(n - 1), 2^n - 2}], 1]]]]
T[n_, k_] := Length[NonCoprimeList[n, k]];
T[8, 3]

Suddenly, it now returns a different result, T[8, 3] = 84.
I spent the whole day trying to figure out why these two codes are not equivalent. I found the triples that the second code "misses" for some reason, e.g. {10100000, 1011010, 101}. This must be included because GCD[10100000, 1011010, 101] == 101.
Can anyone please help me understand what is going on?
Or maybe you can suggest a better way to define this function?

I need more explanation of what you're trying to do. Using your first definition, which you say gives correct results,, NonCoprimeList[4, 2] gives me {{1001, 110}, {1010, 101}, {1100, 11}}. Why should that not include {1111,11}?

And just to make sure I understand, am I correct in assuming that the argument n is meant as a sort of maximum to the search (i.e. you'll only search up to 1111 when n is 4, for example)? And the parameter m is the size of the non-coprime sets you're looking for, correct?

Oh wait, are you looking for sets where the number of appearances of the digit 1 across the whole set is constrained by the argument n?

The integers are complementary, meaning they must add up to a repunit.

n is the length of binary strings, and m is how many there are.

For m=2, these would be pairs of binary strings of length n that are coprime as integers in base 10.

The idea is to consider all integers of length n (they all start with 1), then at positions that are 0's substitute all possible substrings of shorter length that are formed in the same way.

Essentially I am looking for all possible ways to split a repunit of length n into sums of m binary numbers such that they are not setwise coprime.

I haven't yet figured out exactly how, but wrapping your main expression (the thing you set FullList to) with a head causes a change in the evaluation sequence for that main expression. It doesn't have anything to do with Select per se. (And side note, setting FullList is superfluous...maybe you were using it for testing or something?)

As far as I can tell, the change in evaluation order is related to Dot somehow. I originally suspected that it was just resolving your various nested Functions, but analyzing that hasn't yielded anything. It could be a bug, but I'm not quite convinced yet. It may be a case of you getting lucky in your original code--maybe MMA was able to attempt an alternate parse that worked, but it can't do that same alternate when the expression is one level deeper.

OK, so at least I am not getting crazy and you can confirm that you are getting different results too. I thought I had some strange bug I did overlook, but cannot see anything.

Yes. I intend to spend some time looking for a minimal example. The only thing I’ve confirmed so far is that any extra layer causes different behavior—it isn’t restricted to Select. It seems pretty thorny, so may take a while.

Well, I found my error. I refactored your code trying to isolate a step in the recursion where the error occurred...but I refactored incorrectly. My error just completely masked the problem. Trying to refactor again I avoided my previous error, and I think I'm getting close to understanding the actual error, and it seems more like a simple logic error. But I'm out of time for now.

I now understood what the problem was, and it is just my mistake. In the recursive version of the function, it is applying Select to the numbers before I re-order the corresponding digits, which is of course incorrect.

Using KSetPartitions ResourceFunction.
Clear[fu]

fu[n_, m_] := 
 Select[Total[
    10^(ResourceFunction["KSetPartitions"][Range[n], m] - 
       1), {3}] /. (0 -> {}), GCD @@ # > 1 &]

Comparing with your first version of NonCoprimeList and T.
Length[fu @@ #] & /@ Tuples[Range[10], {2}]
T @@ # & /@ Tuples[Range[10], {2}] == %


{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 19, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 1, 47, 98, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 84, 280, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 141, 650, 600, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

True

Comparing performance on fresh kernel:
Length[fu @@ #] & /@ Tuples[Range[10], {2}]; // Timing
T @@ # & /@ Tuples[Range[10], {2}]; // Timing


{4.21875, Null}

{16.6719, Null}


Thanks a lot. This is much more elegant than the messy code I came up with.

The code nevertheless generates all partitions and only then selects them based on GCD. This creates a huge array when we go to lengths n on the order of 13 or more, making things very slow. My idea with the code I was trying to write was to generate the partitions iteratively, i.e. defining the function for m using the same for m-1. This should speed up things a lot.

@Vosoni So you do not not care about the tuples only about how many of them there is?

I want to have the tuples too, but only those with GCD > 1. This is only quite a small fraction of all tuples. So I wanted to avoid generating a huge number of those that are coprime.

I don't think there is a way of getting their number without actually generating them.

My idea was that while generating tuples of, say, 3 numbers, we take all binary numbers of length n, then see how many zeros a particular number has (say, that is k zeros), and the following two numbers we need to consider are essentially pairs of numbers that we can generate with the same function. We don't need to consider pairs that are coprime already. This should speed up things considerably. Therefore I wanted to redefine the function in the form fu[n_, m_] := fu[n,m] = ... --- this idea would probably work with KSetPartitions too.

@Vosoni Couldn't it be that your algorithm has flaws instead of the code? I admit that I do not understand logic of your algorithm.

Well, the algorithm returns correct results for n < 8 and then at certain recursion depth starts skipping terms.

I understood the problem, it is indeed with the algorithm. Probably the recursive idea just doesn't work, so the code you proposed is the best one can do.

@Vosoni What I do not understand about your algorithm is that why the next NonCoprimeList should only depend on number of zeros in previous NonCoprimeList and not also on their position in numbers.

As I wrote above, that was exactly my mistake. The coprimality check should be done after changing the positions of digits, and in the recursive code it was checked before. That is of course wrong.
